# SQL Count elements in pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE aaa AS
(
  ogid integer NOT NULL,
  ocolor character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  vgid integer NOT NULL,
  vcolor character varying(80) NOT NULL,
)
```

aa contains some values, like in this example

```
Ogid OColor Vgid VColor
1   v       1   v
1   v       5   r
1   v       8   g
2   r       5   r
3   g       7   r
4   g       5   r
5   r       7   r
5   r       9   g
6   g       6   g
```

I need to count the number of elements in every couple (OColor, VColor) grouping together simmetric couples ( for example the elements of g-r and r-g go together  ).

I need a result similar to:

```
OColor Vcolor nelement
b      b      10
b      g      16
g      v      2
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: hard to understand data structure. COuld you clarify?

Comment: How come `b` in expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(ocolor, vcolor), greatest(ocolor, vcolor), count(*)
from table t
group by least(ocolor, vcolor), greatest(ocolor, vcolor);
```

However, your question is confusing because the results seem to have nothing to do with the sample data.

Comment: I think this is what OP have been asking for. I was just playing around with it, but here is [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2c311/11/0) for your great solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a simple and brilliant solution!